# getUserMedia creating stream for wrong camera using exact: deviceId

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I've got the following code which loops through all videoinput devices on a machine and should display a stream of that input device.

```
$.each(devices, function( index, value ) {
    if(value.kind == 'videoinput') {

        console.log(value);

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: { exact: value.deviceId }}).then(function(stream) {

            console.log(stream);

            var video = document.createElement('video');
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.autoplay = true;

            var elem = '\
                <div>\
                    <div class="view_camera_' + index + ' uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-small"></div>\
                </div>\
            ';
            outputs.append(elem);

            $('.view_camera_' + index).append(video);

        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

Notice in my selector, I used `{video: { exact: value.deviceId }}`, which should, according to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), should "require the specific camera".

I was originally using `{ video: { deviceId: value.deviceId } }` which actually worked the way I wanted it to, but the documentation says "*The above [using deviceId instead of exact] will return the camera you requested, or a different camera if that specific camera is no longer available*". I do not want it to "return a different camera if that specific camera is no longer available", so I switched over to using the `exact` keyword.

The problem is, this is not working properly. Even though I am passing 2 different deviceId's, it is creating 2 separate streams for the same device.

Here is a picture of my console logs from when the function is running, you can see that there are 2 camera devices with different deviceId's, and there are 2 different streams that are created, however, the 2 video streams displayed on the page are from the same camera.

[image]

Why is getUserMedia using the `exact` keyword creating 2 separate but identical streams from the same camera, instead of 2 separate streams from the 2 separate cameras?

Answer (score 5):

Your selector format is wrong. You missed the `deviceId` in between.

It should be: `{ video: { deviceId: { exact: value.deviceId } } }`

Comment: Oh wow... I can't believe I missed that. That did solve my problem. I still wonder why it makes it behave the way it was.

Comment: It's Friday. That's completely normal :D